# Javascript photo slideshow

Tags: javascript

I want to make a foto-slideshow like the one on the top of this page http://www.southamptontaxis.org/our-partners/.
All I want is to do this only with Javascript, no CSS, no jQuery.
I've tried, but I can't do it, I want some help, not the full code of course, just a useful advice.
Thank you.

Here is my bad code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #container {
                position: relative;
                width: 1000px;
                height: 420px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            img {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 1000px;
                height: 420px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <img src="our-partners.jpg">
            <img src="index.jpg">
            <img src="our-taxis.jpg">
            <img src="pre-book.jpg">
            <img src="join-us.jpg">
            <img src="news.jpg">
            <img src="contact.jpg">
        </div>
        <script>
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            var imgElems = container.querySelectorAll("img");
            var timer = setInterval(f1, 200);
            var n = 0;
            var i = 0;
            function f1() {
                var elem = imgElems[i];
                elem.style.left = n + "px";
                n--;
                i++;
                if (n === (-1000)) {
                    n = 0;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't make a slideshow without CSS. You already have CSS anyway. Obviously with your code it is not going to work. You increment `i` as well everytime so it will get out of bounds and each time you animate the next image a few pixels to the left.

Comment: thank you, you are right JS+CSS, but no jQuery, where should I put i increment? how to make script work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, might help.
http://www.szcchina.com/blog/photo-slideshow-code.html
http://www.jsmadeeasy.com/javascripts/images/list_test.asp

In case you try out jquery for better results, try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() { 
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
</script>


<div id="slideshow">
<div>
<img src="samsung.jpg" style="width: 490px; height: 250px; border-style:ridge;"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="intel.jpg" style="width: 490px; height: 250px; border-style:ridge;"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="snap camera.jpg" style="width: 490px; height: 250px; border-style:ridge;"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="asus.jpg" style="width: 490px; height: 250px; border-style:ridge;"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="cam.jpg" style="width: 490px; height: 250px; border-style:ridge;"/>
</div>
</div>
```